# Отправить JSON как параметр в метод контроллера C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Я пытаюсь получить ответ от сервера с помощью XML HttpRequest:

```
    var commands = "{'Name':'name' , 'Surname':'surname' , 
    'Password':'password' , 'Nick':'nick' , 'Email':'email'}";
    commands = commands.replace("name", Name.value);
    commands = commands.replace("surname", Surname.value);
    commands = commands.replace("password", Password.value);
    commands = commands.replace("nick", Nick.value);
    commands = commands.replace("email", Email.value);


    var sendStr = JSON.stringify(commands);
    console.log(sendStr);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "Register", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(sendStr);
```

Однако при заполнении форм и отправке запроса параметр args оказывается пустым:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public ActionResult Register(string args)
    {
        User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(args);
        if (context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == user.Email) == null 
            && 
            user.Password.Length < 30 && user.Password.Length < 8)
        {
            HashGenerator hash = new HashGenerator(user.Password);
            user.Password = hash.Hash;
            context.User.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
            Session["Id"] = user.Id;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Info");
    }
```

Есть ли способ словить JSON файл в методе контроллера?

Comment: Почему бы не выслать JSON как JSON и принять User как User в контроллере? Зачем вам дополнительные сложности?

Comment: подробнее? можете написать пример кода?

Comment: `public ActionResult Register(User user) { ... }` ?

Comment: а как мне на стороне JS отправить этот параметр так, чтобы метод увидел его?

Comment: `xhr.send({ name: Name.value, surname: Surname.value, .... });`

Comment: [Javascript : Send JSON Object with Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418506/312041)

Comment: хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: там идёт обсуждение PHP, я же работаю с ASP.NET MVC

Comment: думаете, отправка ajax запроса чем то отличается для PHP или ASP.NET?

Comment: Меньше слов, больше дела, `xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ name: Name.value, surname: Surname.value, .... }));`

Comment: спасибо! всё работает!

Comment: На здоровье. Хорошо, что завелось.